# Solr special Sorting

Tags: sorting, solr

I have Text field in solr that I would like it to be sorted in special manner

```
title 
-------
The Book 
When Available
```

Since the (when,on) words are included in my stop words list when I query and sort asc the fields I would like them to appear as :

```
When Available ( first  ) 
The  Book       ( second )
```

So far I've tried it with various combinations of

```
<fieldType name="sortString" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
   <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>

    .......
   </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

and so on, with no success, 
Is it possible to achieve this ??

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this will not work.

The stopword filtering filters out tokens that match your stopwords, but the keyword tokenizer doesn't actually break the text into multiple tokens. Since the entire title is one token and isn't one of your stopwords, the filter does nothing.

And yet, you can't use any other tokenizer in a sort text field.

So I see two options:

One, use PatternReplaceFilter to apply regular expressions and match/remove your stopwords within the unbroken text value.

Two, remove the stopwords within code that prepares your Solr documents for submission to Solr.

Both have significant disadvantages compared to the builtin Solr stopword filter. I personally use option two pretty heavily. The first option could get extremely difficult to manage with more than a few stopwords.